# Calculating distances in a datraframe

Tags: r, datetime, distance, na

I have a large dataframe with one column with time and a second column with speed measurements (km/h). Here is an short example of the database:

```
df <- data.frame(time = as.POSIXct(c("2019-04-01 13:55:18", "2019-04-01 14:03:18",
                                     "2019-04-01 14:14:18", "2019-04-01 14:26:55",
                                     "2019-04-01 14:46:55", "2019-04-01 15:01:55")),
                 speed = c(4.5, 6, 3.2, 5, 4, 2))
```

Is there any way to do a new dataframe, which calculates the distance driven every 20 minutes, from 2019-04-01 14:00:00 to 2019-04-01 15:00:00? assuming that the speed changes are linear. I was trying to find solutions with integrals, but was not sure if it is the correct way to do it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just to be clear, the speed from 13:55:18 to 14:03:18 is 4.5 kmh, from then until 14:26:55 its 6kmh and so on. Within these intervals the speed is constant and you would like to know how much distance was covered every 20 minutes?

Comment: from 14:00 to 14:20 it would be 14:18 with 4.5 and 5:42 with 6kmh?

Comment: okay, i missed the second interval. so it would be three different speeds in the first 20 minutes

Comment: Should have explained better. The speed would increase linearly. So it is not constant. So between 13:55:18 and 14:03:18 the speed is increasing from 4.5 to 6km/h.

Comment: Ah interesting. Good luck :)

Comment: You should start calculating the seconds from start, then add groups based on your 20 minute intervals and see how many seconds are then within each speed group. Then you calculate the weighted average based on the speeds and the time for each of them within your 20 minutes block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using a combination of `zoo::na.approx` and `dplyr` functions.

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

seq = data.frame(time = seq(min(df$time),max(df$time), by = 'secs'))
df <- merge(seq,df,all.x=T)
df$speed <- na.approx(df$speed)

df %>%
  filter(time >= "2019-04-01 14:00:00" & time < "2019-04-01 15:00:00") %>% 
  mutate(km = speed/3600) %>% 
  group_by(group = cut(time, breaks = "20 min")) %>% 
  summarise(distance = sum(km))
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  group               distance
  <fct>                  <dbl>
1 2019-04-01 14:00:00     1.50
2 2019-04-01 14:20:00     1.54
3 2019-04-01 14:40:00     1.16
```

**Explanation:**
The first step is to create a sequence of time frames to compute the speed between two times points (`seq`). The sequence is then merged with the data frame and NAs are filled using `na.approx`.

Then, using `dplyr` verbs, the data frame is filtered, and the 20 minutes sequences are created using `cut`. The final distance is the sum of every 1-sec distance in the 20 minutes time frame.